# How to quickly figure out which list is causing the error?

Tags: python, list, exception

In a python script, if we have multiple lists in a single expression, for example:

```
a[1] = b[2] + c[3] + d[4]
```

OR

```
a[1] = b[c[d[1]]] # (This case added in EDIT)
```

Now, one of these lists throws an error `IndexError: List Index Out of Range`  because the index is higher than the list length.

Is there a way to improve this default exception handling using `try/except` statements such that we can instantly figure out which list caused the problem?

Otherwise, one needs to check each list using a command line debugger. I understand that if an IDE is available, then this feature is probably inbuilt into the IDE.

Comment: Unlikely, because python doesn't tell you which part of the line caused the error. You _could_ try to access the elements from each list individually in the except clause and that'll throw another error, but that's not very scalable

Comment: If you care about which list raised the exception, you should index each one in a separate `try` statement, so that it's unambiguous which list was involved.

Comment: just read the release notes for upcoming python 3.11; they solved this exact issue! :) I wrote it as an answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530238/3896008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact issue has been addressed and will be available in the  python-3.11 interpreter . Reproduced below from the release notes:
"When printing tracebacks, the interpreter will now point to the exact expression that caused the error instead of just the line. For example:"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distance.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(manhattan_distance(p1, p2))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "distance.py", line 6, in manhattan_distance
    return abs(point_1.x - point_2.x) + abs(point_1.y - point_2.y)
                           ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'
```

References:

[Release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#summary-release-highlights)
and
[PEP657](https://peps.python.org/pep-0657/)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to artificially split the line over several lines. For example:

```
b =[1]
c = []
d = [1]

a = b[0] + \
    c[0] + \
    d[0]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "/tmp/foo.py", line 7, in <module>
    c[0] + \
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: this unfortunately won't work if you declare the lines with a leading `+`, for ex. like `+ c[0] \ ` instead. I dunno why this is, tbh.

Comment: Yes! I think this can be a feasible workaround; But usually there  can be nested items as well, for example `a[b[c[0]]]`

Comment: The same trick with `\\` can be done with nested vars.

Comment: @match got it! I will test it And accept the answer if that works; however is there a tool to automatically split this after every variable, that would be cool, doing it manually is not scalable

Comment: @match could you include a line on black auto formatter.  I tested with black code formatter. `black -l 1 file.py` where `1` is the number of characters per line makes your answer scalable. I tried to edit your answer, but the edit  queue is full right now, wil try again tomorrow

Comment: A comment is enough to answer a comment - you shouldn't add existing answers to add answers to different questions really - better create a new question and then answer it yourself for others to find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

another option could be to use `inspect` module to find the line number that raised the error. This requires you to modify the addition `+` assignment to use local vars previously defined like `bv = b[2]` though, or else split it over individual lines as shown.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1] * 3
c = [2] * 3
d = [3] * 5

try:
    a[1] = b[2] + \
           c[3] + \
           d[4]

except IndexError:
    from inspect import trace
    var = trace()[0].code_context[0].split('=', 1)[-1].split('[', 1)[0].lstrip(' +-*')
    print(f'The variable that raised the IndexError was: {var}')
```

Out:

```
The variable that raised the IndexError was: c
```

---

*Interesting fact:* the following syntax, which I actually consider good coding practice, actually does *not* behave how you want for an informative stack trace. I have no idea why, unfortunately.

```py
    a[1] = b[2] \
           + c[3] \
           + d[4]
```